# PGF/TikZ error when using chains

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I'm trying to learn how to use PGF/TikZ to draw pictures, in particular a chain of nodes.

I have the following picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, node distance=5mm]
  \node [on chain,join] {$t_\mathrm{opt flow}$};  
  \node [on chain,join] {$foo$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would expect this to yield two nodes connected by a simple
line. Instead, when I run LaTex, I get the following error:

```
./NIQ_Principles.tex:39: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of'.
./NIQ_Principles.tex:40: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\endpgfpicture ... \pgf@y }\endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                  \pgf@insertlayers \endgrou...
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is my complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [start chain, node distance=5mm]
  \node [on chain,join] {foo};  
  \node [on chain,join] {bar};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output I get:

```
ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of'.

--- TeX said ---

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10   \node [on chain,join]
                             {bar};
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

I can't really claim that I'm as smart as Mr Poirot, so can someone
point me in the right direction?

Comment: With a ecm "example complete and minimal" perhaps i's possible to give a correct answer. Your example compiles with pgf 2.1 and the library `chains` (with pdflatex and latex). Do you try an example from the pgfmanual ? you can see if you miss something or see if you need to install a correct version of pgf

Comment: Package PGF Math Error ? perhaps you have two versions of pgf on your distribution ?

Comment: @Altermundus I've added a complete example to the question, one that doesn't work on my machine but which is very close to the examples given in the TikZ documentation.

Comment: your example works with pgf 2.1 cvs without error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the `pgf` package installed under Ubuntu was version 2.00, whereas the latest version (and the one from whose documentation I was trying the examples) was 2.10.

Installing the latest version of `pgf` under my local `texmf` tree solved the problem.

Comment: It would be great of you accept your answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer.